# Liferay PDF upload log error

Tags: java, pdf, liferay, liferay-6

My platform is **Liferay 6.2 EE Tomcat bundle** using **Advanced File system hook for document repository**.

I found an issue where uploading a PDF document to the repository generates the following error in the logs:

```
1:06:09,564 WARN  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.process.ProcessExecutor-2][ProcessExecutor:547] Found corrupt leading log Loading jar:file:/export/../liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp2/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties_Loading file:/export/../liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp2/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/system-ext.properties_ [Sanitized]
```

This occurs for me when uploading the PDF only. There are no errors in the logs or any issues when accessing the PDF after upload or when downloading the PDF.

Anyone else has seen this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a similar issue reported on [LPS-41067](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-41067), which reports that it occurs on startup.

Since this is a known bug, we are working with Liferay support to get a patch for this.

Hope someone finds this useful.